# Can you geotag a photo in android and upload coordinates?

Tags: android

i have an app in which you upload a photo to a database, i was wondering if it is possible to upload coordinates of where the image has been captured, is this done as standard with every picture taken? will it be as simple as getting the data and posting it along with the rest of the data i am sending

Thanks

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Android camera app geotags a picture IF the user has explicitly enabled this feature (it's disabled by default).

In case of JPEG files, the coordinates are embedded in the EXIF data. You can use Android's `ExifInterface` to inject/extract that information.

Comment: No problem! Please remember to accept answers so both you and the answerer get rep points.